# Latex: Rearange table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, tabularray

I use the following code to produce a slide of tables in Beamer.
Unfortunately, I'd need to rearange them. The two tables should be next to each other.

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{}
    \begin{frame}
        \tiny
        \begin{table}
            \captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
            \begin{+array}{colspec={Q[wd=0.568\linewidth]},delimiter={right=.,left=.}}
                \caption{}
                \vspace{-1ex}
                \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                    Table entry A&a\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry B&b\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry C&c\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry D&d\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry E&e\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \begin{+array}{colspec={@{} l}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=.}}
                    {Table entry E1)\\
                    Table entry E2}
                    \end{+array}
                    &f\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry F&f=\qty{10}{km}\\
                    Table entry G&g\sim\qty{10}{km}\\ 
                \end{tblr}\\[-1ex]
                    \caption{}
                    \begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
                        Quantity A&a\sim\qty{10}{kg}\\
                        Quantity B&b=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity C&c=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity D&d=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                        Quantity E&e=\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
                    \end{tblr}  
%                \end{+array}
            \end{+array}            
        \end{table}
        %\framezoom<1><2>[border=1](9cm,3.8cm)(2cm,0.5cm)
        %\framezoom<1><3>[border=1](0cm,5.5cm)(2cm,0.5cm)
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there a straightforward way to do that?

Comment: Use `columns`, like in [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700956/36296)

Comment: Could you help out once more? :D I'll ask for the last time

Comment: What's the purpose of having `table` and specifying `\caption{}`?

Answer (score 0):

Beamer provides the `columns` environment to place stuff besides each other on the frame:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{}
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          content of first column
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
          content of second column
        \end{column}
      \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It makes little sense to use `table` without specifying a caption.

Just place the two tables next to each other with some space in between.

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
  Table entry A&a\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry B&b\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry C&c\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry D&d\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry E&e\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  \setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}%
  \begin{+array}{colspec={@{}l@{}}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=\}}}
    Table entry E1\\
    Table entry E2
  \end{+array}
    &f\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry F&f=\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry G&g\sim\qty{10}{km}\\ 
\end{tblr}\qquad
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
  Quantity A&a\sim\qty{10}{kg}\\
  Quantity B&b={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
  Quantity C&c={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
  Quantity D&d={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
  Quantity E&e={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
\end{tblr}  

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I made some fixes to the first table, notably setting `\nulldelimiterspace` to `0pt` in order to get the alignment right. I also added a grouping brace.

Note also the braces around `\sim` when used as a unary operator.

[image]

If you want captions, then use `columns`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} %tables
\usepackage{siunitx} %units, numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[
  %singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{columns}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{table}
\caption{Some caption for this table}

\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
  Table entry A&a\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry B&b\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry C&c\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry D&d\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry E&e\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  \setlength{\nulldelimiterspace}{0pt}%
  \begin{+array}{colspec={@{}l@{}}, rowsep=1pt, delimiter={left=.,right=\}}}
    Table entry E1\\
    Table entry E2
  \end{+array}
    &f\sim\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry F&f=\qty{10}{km}\\
  Table entry G&g\sim\qty{10}{km}\\ 
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{column}

\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}

\begin{table}
\caption{Some caption for this table, longer than the previous one to see what happens}

\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z},colspec={@{} l Q[l, mode={math}] @{}},rowsep=1pt}
  Quantity A&a\sim\qty{10}{kg}\\
  Quantity B&b={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
  Quantity C&c={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
  Quantity D&d={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
  Quantity E&e={\sim}\qty{10}{km}\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{column}

\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]